# GDI+ transparent bitmap on Windows 7

Tags: winapi, gdi+, gdi

I have transparent pngs embedded in my application. I load the bytes, pre-multiply the alpha and use `CreateBitmap` to create an `HBITMAP`:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, 32, bytes);
```

Normally I used `AlphaBlend` to scale and draw those images inside the application, and it works well. However, I note that when running the application in a Windows 7 RDP session, no images are drawn. I suppose this is because of the reduced color depth (it appears to be either 16 or 24 bit color). I cannot reproduce that on Windows 10; since I seem to be unable to force a color depth lower than 32 bit...

---

I have read that GDI+ is the more modern graphics API and I should try to use that instead of regular GDI. I write the code as follows:

```
    m_hDisplayBitmap = // the earlier created HBITMAP
    int srcDim = 64;
    int destDim = 32;

    // WM_PAINT
    // dc = BeginPaint(// etc...)

    Graphics g(dc);

    BITMAPINFO bmInfo = { 0 };
    bmInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmInfo.bmiHeader);

    // Get the BITMAPINFO from the source HBITMAP
    GetDIBits(dc, m_hDisplayBitmap, 0, 0, nullptr, &bmInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    bmInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = -bmInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight;
    bmInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    BYTE* lpPixels = new BYTE[bmInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage];

    // Get the bits from the source HBITMAP
    GetDIBits(dc, m_hDisplayBitmap, 0, bmInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, (LPVOID) lpPixels, &bmInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    // Create a GDI+ bitmap from the source bits
    Gdiplus::Bitmap sourceBmp(bmInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth, sourceDim, bmInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth * (bmInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount / 8), PixelFormat32bppPARGB, lpPixels);

    // Create a GDI+ bitmap of the destination dimensions, and draw the source into it
    Gdiplus::Bitmap* destBmp = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(destDim, destDim);
    Graphics gx(destBmp);
    gx.DrawImage(&sourceBmp, 0, 0);

    // Create a cached bitmap and draw to the screen
    Gdiplus::CachedBitmap m_cachedBitmap = new Gdiplus::CachedBitmap(destBmp, &g);
    Gdiplus::Status s = g.DrawCachedBitmap(m_cachedBitmap, 0, 0); // Status is `Ok`

    // Cleanup
```

On Windows 10, my bitmap displays at the expected size, with transparency:

[image]

On Windows 7, with any display settings, I instead get a gray blob:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `m_hDisplayBitmap` is always 32-bit. How is it created? You say you are working with PNG files. Why don't you just use GDI plus to load the PNG file?

Comment: The image data is embedded, there is no file for GDI+ to load. I can confirm, at least in the specific example in my question, that the image data is 32-bit.

Comment: GDI+ can load image from memory or resource. How are you loading the PNG image currently?

Comment: Using libpng, then `CreateBitmap` to get an `HBITMAP`

Comment: Just to clarify: on Win 7, using GDI+, you get the "gray blob" even without RDP, with 32 bpp display mode?

Comment: @zett42 Correct

Comment: How many bits is your window 7 system? x86 or x64?

Comment: I suspect this is related to the system, because the same code can successfully display the transparent bitmap on win10, but it can't display normally on win7. Until I see [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3fe68809-586f-4264-a91e-326df9d13dfe/not-able-to-get-transparent-bitmap-image-on-64-bit-windows-7-and-windows-2008-r2-enterprise?forum=vcgeneral), I am not sure if this is the same as yours, but I think Is worthy of reference.

Comment: Use `Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromStream` to load bitmap directly from resources